# ProgressDialog in another AsyncTask class not showing when called from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a class called `RestClient` that gets some information from my webService and then return and I'm trying to make a Progress dialog run while it is accessing the internet. And as I use this class in more than one place I won't make in the Activity itself. Here is my `RestClient` class:

```
public class RestClient extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {

    private Context context;
    private String string;
public RestClient(Context context, String string)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.string = string;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Buscando seu Produto","Por favor, espere um momento...",true ,false);
    //I've already tried:
    /*ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle("Buscando seu Produto");
    dialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere um momento...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);*/

    dialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
    try {

        //Some WebService gets and Json conversions using my string variable
        //and some Thread.sleep that counts 2000 miliseconds to do all the queries

        dialog.dismiss();

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException |JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        dialog.dismiss();

        return e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);


   }
}
```

And in my activity I call the class `RestClient` when I click a button like this:

**--- EDIT : I forgot to mention that I have an AlertDialog in this same activity that CAN be shown sometimes before and after the ProgressDialog ---**

```
private Button buttonConfirm;
     private EditView evString;

     private String theString;
     private String returnFromExecute;

     private RestClient restClient;


     private AlertDialog.Builder dialog;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_access_webservice);

            evString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editViewMyString);
            buttonConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConfirm);

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(IdentificacaoDeProdutoActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Error");
            dialog.setMessage("Please try again");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);


            buttonConfirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)  {                  
                    theString = evString.getText().toString();
                    if(!(theString!=null && theString.trim().length()>0)) //To check if theString is not null
                    {
                          dialog.show();
                    }

                    restClient = new RestClient(AccessWebserviceActivity.this, theString);

                    //Then I call execute and put a Thread.sleep a bit longer to compensate the ones I have in my doInBackground
                    restClient.execute();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2050);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        dialog.show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that my `ProgressDialog` never shows. I've already tried `getParent()`, `getApplication()` and `getApplicationContext()` instead of `AccessWebserviceActivity.this` but none have worked. Someone Have any idea what is happening and what should I do?

Comment: can you tell me your  AsyncTask class is child of your Activity class or AsnctaskClass have different package?

Comment: @AmeerHamza, it is not a child of my Activity because I use it in other Activities, but yes it isn't in the same package my activity is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researches about Threads and Process I found out that I had to encapsulate the all the code I have after my 
`RestClient.execute` in a

`new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { // My code } });`

so that the execution of the code happened in background as well as the WebService query.

EDIT:

Even if creating a new Thread works, it is not recommended! The right thing to do would be to create **another class that extends AsyncTask** to do job.

Answer (score 1):

you have not created progress dialog try this.

```
ProgressDialog dialog;

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("on Progress");
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

Comment: Don't negativate my question, please. Is not that simple. This progress bar simply do not appear no matter what.

Comment: I am not doing anything wrong bro I am surprised why my answer does not work for you.

Comment: That's ok. I've tried everything that every blog and every solution said but it didn't work.

Comment: try new  RestClient(AccessWebserviceActivity.this).execute(theString);

Comment: Can't do that, I make some alterations in this string in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Buscando seu Produto","Por favor, espere um momento...",true ,false);
```

and remove

```
 dialog.show();
```

Also put your `dialog.dismiss()`; method in `onPostExecute`(). This `dialog.dismiss()` method is good in catch block but what's its purpose if you are calling this method in try block. It will remove progress dialog as soon as you call this `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Have you removed dismiss method from try block in doInBackground method? If you are getting any error then paste that so someone could help you.

Comment: Yes I have. I've just put it there because somewhere said this could be one of the problems but haven't worked,

Comment: I get a `I/Choreographer: Skipped 126 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Comment: why are you doing this? Thread.sleep(2050);
AsyncTask's doInBackground works in background and dialog shows on UI. Read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I have this UI Thread.sleep to wait for my background task to end. I use a return of it in my application right after and if i do not have this break throws me a Null Excepition.

Answer (score 0):

```
returnFromExecute = restClient.get();
```

Remove that statement. You have already:

```
restClient.execute();
```

That should do.

The result of `doInBackground()` you should handle in `onPostExecute()`. It cannot be handled or retrieved in `onCreate()`.